# Band Ratios in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, band-ratio

I am trying to execute in mapcalc a simple band ratio exercise.
I have set new map as "Band 12"
and entered this equation into mapcalc:

```
Band12== Band1@MApset/Band2@Mapset
```

I hit "Run" but I keep getting this answer: Invalid Map .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set the region? https://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/grass5tutor/HTML_en/c515.html

Comment: (there is a better page: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region )

Comment: You used a double == here but it needs to be single = (see Micha's answer below for the complete answer)

Answer (score 1):

The correct function calls and mapcalc expression should be:

```
g.region -ap rast=Band1,Band2
r.mapcalc "Band12 = Band1 / Band2"
```

Note the spaces around the ' = ' sign